# Binding an ImageSource object directly to an Image source in XAML/WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, imagesource

I have the following XAML code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}">  
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>  
        <DataTemplate>  
            <StackPanel>  
                <Image Source="{Binding LanguageIcon}" />  
                <Label Content="{Binding LanguageName}" />  
            </StackPanel>  
        </DataTemplate>  
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>  
</ListBox>
```

and in the model class:

```
class Language {  
    public string LanguageName;  
    public ImageSource LanguageIcon;  
}
```

my modelview class contains:

```
public List<Language> Languages;
```

which gets filled with:

```
Languages.Add(new Language("A",new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/a.ico",
    UriKind.Relative))));  
Languages.Add(new Language("B",new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/b.ico",
    UriKind.Relative))));
```

When I run the project, all my language names are shown in the list, but not the icons... Why does this happen and how can I ensure that my icons are shown? (I am sure that the resources do exist as the BitmapImages don't throw errors)

Comment: I think you should reconsider your concept and use a enum for the language. In xaml you could use valueconverters to convert the enum to the language name and icon.

Comment: The problem you are having is the Image.Source on the object is an ImageSource object, however when it is exposed through Xaml it is a string for an Uri. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your Uri path to...

```
"../Resources/a.ico"
```

**EDIT**:

If you are trying to reference the images in a differing assembly try using the [pack syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)...

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Resources/a.ico
```

...where `ReferencedAssembly` is the assembly containing your images.

Comment: Ok but now I put my c# code (and also the resource images) into an other assembly - in the remote assembly the images can get loaded now but when I want to bind them at the local assembly, no icon is shown...although the image can be loaded... strange :/

Comment: @A Bothe While I did answer your initial question...I edited the answer to provide a solution to your follow-up question

Comment: So it is not possible to e.g. load a BitmapImage within the one assembly and use it (for instance create an Image control whereas the Source is that BitmapImage-instance) in the other assembly?

Comment: @A Bothe It is possible. You can reference a BitmapImage in one assembly from a differing assembly and set the Image.Source in code behind with that BitmapImage and it will be displayed, if you are setting the DataContext of the Image to the referenced BitmapImage from a differing assembly that will also work...if you are having issues posting additional details about the assemblies may help...
I

Comment: ok I noticed now that the icon hasn't even been loaded in the satellite assembly. I tried to load the image via pack://application:,,,/MyApp.ExtAssembly;/a.ico   whereas MyApp.ExtAssembly is the name of my satellite assembly and a.ico is located in the root folder of the project. Anyway, it throws everytime because it just couldn't find it... strange... (and yes, I made a.ico to be compiled as resource :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the error reason but still no solution -

The "Resources/a.ico" **simply wasn't found** - so it's **no XAML problem** anymore.

But it's that circumstance that a.ico is located in an other Assembly. So now the question is: 
How to get to this icon?

Now I used the `pack://application:,,,/MyApp.ExtAssembly;/Resources/a.ico` - but it always throw an exception that it wasn't found...

Comment: Problem workarounded: I simply put the icons into a resx file, load them into a BitmapImage Resource when needed - and that's it :D .. anyway, thanks to everyone who supported me!